# file_get_contents() returns all local/short links as 404

Tags: php

I am currently setting up a site, which requires some sort of "proxy" work. Basically through `$_GET['url']` I can grab a site's content using `file_get_contents($url)`. However, when links are shown like: `<a href="images/image.png".../>`, they will link to my site instead of theirs, which makes all images, links, etc. load from my site, which returns a 404 not found error.

I have not been able to find anything about this anywhere. How I do the "proxying" in theory, but not as a final product:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$content = file_get_contents($url);
echo $content;
```

What could I possibly do to change this, so all links doesn't depend on what the browser sees, but where they actually come from (the site link in `$_GET['url']`), which basically turns relative links into absolute? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean having the server respond your file_get_contents($url) with content that is part on that server and part on your local machine?
Without you having access for programing scripts in the server itself?
You can't do that. Does the server have at least a 'sight' of your local machine through DNS?

Comment: @JulioSoares Nope. Read the post. Treat it like a proxy, where the `$_GET['url']` is a link to an external site. I never said anything about a local machine or anything being local.

Comment: So, all you ned to do is parse the content you got from file_get_contents($url) and replace tha tags you want before echoing to the screen

Comment: @JulioSoares Easier said than done, when not all links are relative. Some are absolute, so I can't just replace href="(.*)" with the new path + $1 (you get what I mean). A lot of checking is involved, and I'm sure there is a better way of doing this

Comment: Still, all you need is the right criteria. Only you knows exactly what you want to replace and what not. 
It will never work unless you can express that in a way the script would understand

Comment: @JulioSoares It's a hacky way and it won't work properly. It requires a lot of testing and tweaking until it's "almost" perfect. I'm sure there is another way, which is why I made this thread. Apparently someone thought this wasn't a good question, so they voted it down, but didn't leave an answer. That's just stupid, but hey, that just proves this hasn't been asked and answered before.

Comment: The thing is, you ARE hacking a page. There is no elegant way of doing it.
Either you have access to that remote server and program it to talk to your server and present everything neat from the start or... you can't avoid hacking and it's implied imperfections.
That is probably why your question has been marked down.

Comment: @JulioSoares In Javascript you can get the absolute path of any link, even if they start off as relative (/image/image.png for instance). Surely there's an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: @JulioSoares Seems like there was an easy fix. Two lines is all it takes. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to know what their site is in order to make a request from it.

To do this, you can parse the url:

```
$urlParsed = parse_url($url);

$urlHostOnly= $urlParsed['scheme'] . "://" . $urlParsed['host'] . "/";
```

Then, the tricky part, you have to prepend the host only url to each link.

Most links in html are in hrefs and src values so here is a simple replacer to deal with those.

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);

$replaced_content = preg_replace(
    "/(href|src)=\"((?!http[s]:\/\/[a-z\.]{2,6}).*)\"/",
    "$1=\"$urlHostOnly$2\"",
    $content
);
```

Now that you have the replaced contents, echo it to the client

```
echo $replaced_content;
```

Note: There can be some conflict with respect to stylesheets and ssl if you do not specify the correct protocol (http / https) when entering the url.

See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBh4d.png for an example of this.

Comment: Solved this with an advice from a friend. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I've solved this from an advice from a friend.

```
//grabs the URL of the site I am working with (the $_GET['url'] site basically)
$fullUrl = basename($url); 

//Replaces <head> with <head> followed by a base-tag, which has the href attribute of the website.
//This will make all relative links absolute to that base-tag href.
$content = str_replace("<head>", "<head>\n<base href='http://" . $fullUrl . "' />", $content);

echo $content;
```

Voilá, this site now functions perfectly.

---

---

EDIT: Okay, it did not work perfectly.. for some reason. If the URL linked to a file like `help.asp`, `basename()` would return with `help.asp`. I went with a different route:

```
function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
$url = addhttp($url);
preg_match('/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)/', $url, $fullUrl);
$fullUrl = $fullUrl[1];
```

No more wrong URLs being loaded. This all work... for now.